# Auto resize QTableWidget pyside

Tags: python, pyside, qtablewidget

I have a simple code that Creates a QTableWidget. Problem is when I resize the window, columns of QTableWidget are not automatically adjusted to fit entire screen

Please find the snippet below:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
table = QTableWidget(1,3)
table.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one that controls the width of the columns is the `horizontalHeader()`, the solution is to set `QHeaderView::Stretch` using the method `setResizeMode()`.

```
import sys

from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QTableWidget, QHeaderView
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    table = QTableWidget(1,3)
    table.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```